# Case Statement Set Parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

```
SELECT (CASE
        WHEN(percentage >= @Start AND percentage < @End)                        
        THEN 
            SET @body ='<html><body><H3>Report</H3>
                        <table border = 1> 
                        <tr>
                        <th>No </th> <th> date </th> <th> lag </th> <th> Variance </th></tr>'    
            SET @body = @body + @xml +'</table></body></html>' 
        ELSE 'NULL' END) as Variance  
    FROM TestTbl
```

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure SP_CheckDB, Line 31
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SET'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure SP_CheckDB, Line 36
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ELSE'

Kindly help with this statement

Thanks

Comment: `CASE` is an *expression* - it produces a *value*. It's *not* a control flow statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this

```
Declare @str VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @str = '<html><body><H3>Report</H3>
            <table border = 1> 
            <tr>
                <th>No </th> <th> date </th> 
                <th> lag </th> <th> Variance </th>
            </tr>'+ @xml +'</table></body></html>' 


SELECT (CASE
        WHEN(percentage >= @Start AND percentage < @End)                        
        THEN @str
        ELSE 'NULL' END) as Variance  
FROM TestTbl
```

*OR*

```
DECLARE @body VARCHAR(MAX) = 'NULL'

    IF(percentage >= @Start AND percentage < @End) THEN
    BEGIN
        SET @body ='<html><body><H3>Report</H3>
                    <table border = 1> 
                    <tr>
                        <th>No </th> <th> date </th> 
                        <th> lag </th> <th> Variance </th>
                    </tr>'    
        SET @body = @body + @xml +'</table></body></html>' 
    END

    SELECT Variance = @body
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the conditional assignment, then you need to do like so:

```
SELECT TOP 1 @body = (CASE
        WHEN(percentage >= @Start AND percentage < @End)                        
        THEN 
             '<html><body><H3>Report</H3>
                        <table border = 1> 
                        <tr>
                        <th>No </th> <th> date </th> <th> lag </th> <th> Variance </th></tr>'    
            + @xml +'</table></body></html>' 
        ELSE 'NULL' 
        END)
 FROM TestTbl
```

Although note that you can't Assign + Select from within the same statement.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT @body=(CASE WHEN(percentage >= @Start AND percentage < @End)                        
        THEN ('<html><body><H3>Report</H3>
                        <table border = 1> 
                        <tr>
                        <th>No </th> <th> date </th> <th> lag </th> <th> Variance </th></tr>'+@xml +'</table></body></html>')
        ELSE 'NULL' END) as Variance  
    FROM TestTbl
```